# Linhas temporárias em objetos criados em runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, runtime

Ao criar objetos em runtime no firemonkey aparecem diversas linhas ao redor do objeto, na imagem abaixo um tlayout, ao redimensionar o form ou passar o mouse em cima da linha ela some, acontece com Timages, Trectangles, Tlayouts e outros componentes.

Alguém saberia resolver esse erro na interface?

Tlayout aparecendo as linhas

[image: erro em objeto criado em runtime]

Tlayout após redimensionar o form

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
lay:= TLayout.Create(Rectangle);
lay.BeginUpdate;
lay.Parent:= Rectangle;
lay.Align:= TAlignLayout.client;
lay.EndUpdate;
```

Comment: tem algum style carregado?

Comment: não, não tem nenhum, estou criando tudo em runtime e sem carregar style